# How can i change the y axis position in dimple

Tags: html, css, d3.js, data-visualization, dimple.js

Here is my plot for now:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
<div id="chartContainer">
  <script src="/lib/d3.v3.4.8.js"></script>
  <script src="/dist/dimple.v2.2.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 460);
    d3.csv("/dataset/data_pared.csv", function (data) {
      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
      myChart.setBounds(80, 80, 480, 300)
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "mean_wealth");
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "mean_math");
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("z", "n");
      myChart.addSeries("PARED_cut1", dimple.plot.bubble);
      myChart.addLegend(60, 10, 510, 20, "right");
      myChart.draw();
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

The y axis looks annoyingly, then how can i put it at the left side of my chart?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis#position

Comment: Thank you~ i also found this. As said, "The first y axis created will cross the first x axis at zero. " My problem may be, how can i change that.

Comment: Where is the second y axis positioned?

Comment: If i named a second y axis, it will be placed at the right side. But i don't have a second y axis.

Comment: Can you please provide fiddle or jsbin working code. maybe setting `var myAxis = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "mean_math"); myAxis.overrideMin = -2.0; `